# Best practice for controlling amount of installs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I'm (soon to be) graduate working on my first ever public release of a program and my ceo/boss' want to manage/"lockdown" the amount of times a client installs our software, I'm looking for the best practices for this or just best advice on how to do some sort of control on installs. I'm using the Visual Studio Custom Install Shield utility! I'm also working in C#, wpf, mvvm, if that really matters. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this point you in the right direction?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092417/how-to-limit-the-number-of-installations-on-a-setup-package

Comment: One method would be to require online registration. You would then issue a license that is used each time the user installs the software. You would track all of the seat licenses and install counts on your end. This way, if they require or want more installs, your support staff or website would be able to increase the allowed installs upon purchase.

Comment: Why does it matter how many times it is installed?  How does 5 vs 1 negatively impact anything?  Are you really asking about copy protection (much broader than install count).

Comment: No matter what you do, people *will* crack it if your software is useful enough. I can only urge you to make the DRM as painless as possible. You will never defeat piracy 100%. gmiley has the best approach here, though depending on the software, online registration might not be feasible (if it's POS software, for example).

Comment: @Rob - "make DRM as painless as possible" should always be the top priority when approaching this subject. I am usually against DRM as it is (danger: made up figure ahead...) 99% ineffective, and usually just ends up frustrating your paying customers, while the ones not paying will usually find a way around it.

Comment: @Plutonix i dont really understand why it matters, it's my boss making this decision

Comment: I guess you are going on the assumption that a non-tech person (a ceo) has accurately expressed *what* they want in those words.  A bold decision on your part.

Comment: @Plutonix no I dont believe he has expressed what he wants very accurately and I don't think he understands what he's asking for. Each tiered service has a certain amount of users that can be signed in at once, and I thought that would suffice, but now he's getting paranoid about people "abusing" the system or some crap like that lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm moving my comment down as an answer; this is a fairly broad subject though...

As I mentioned in my comment, you would likely want to require online registration during the install process. During the install, the user would need to fill out their registration info that gets submitted to your registration servers. You can offer them a choice of different seat license packages starting from a "Free 30-day trial" up to an "Enterprise" edition with 20 seats, and free upgrades for 2 years (or whatever).  As an extra bit of assurance that your product remains un-pirated, you may want to require the license authentication each time (or every so many days) upon the start-up of the program.

The benefit of this model is that you control the number of installs on your end. If the user needs more installs, they can contact your support staff, or go to your website, and purchase more seats/installs. Having an online central authentication server also makes it a bit harder (but not impossible) to pirate your software. Of course though, now we start into the realm of security and loss-prevention versus ease of use for your customers. But that is whole other subject for another time.

You may want to look around for a pre-built solution. I am sure there are services/products out there that do just this, that you can incorporate into your product.

Comment: Why the down-vote? I don't mind, if there is really a valid reason, but I believe my answer provides the information the OP requested with as much detail as would be possible for such a question...If you are going to vote an answer down, then it would be beneficial to provide a reason for it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! and sorry for having such a broad question, but my company actually does have a tiered payment service but obviously no license authentication. I will look more into this method and get this implemented ASAP! Again thank you for the detailed response!

Comment: That's good to hear. If this helped, could you accept it as your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Accepted it! @gmiley